# javascript closures practical usecase

Tags: javascript

i was reading about  closure on [mdn site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

on the practical section, they provided following code as a practical use case of closure

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
```

i would appreciate if someone explains to me what is differences

**between**

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
```

**and**

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
```

both can be used the same way

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

so what is the necessity of using closure (first example) ?

Comment: "both can be used the same way". No they cannot. Try and see

Comment: You have misinterpreted the usage of first example in those docs. `element.onclick =` expects a function and second example doesn't return a function it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They, in fact, cannot be used in the same way. As the first `makeSizer` is returning a function, the function's contents can only be run if invoked.

Take a look at the code snippet and its comments:

```js
function makeSizer() { // returning a function
  return function() {
    console.log("sizerOne");
  };
}

function makeSizer2() { // not returning a function
  console.log("sizerTwo");
}

var output = makeSizer(); // storing the returned function in an output variable. 
output(); // calling makeSizer's returned function. ie: makeSizer()();

makeSizer2(); // calling makeSizer2()
```